# PHP Array Only Returning One Result to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I'm relatively new to PHP, so please excuse my ignorance if this is an easy one.

I am pulling in results from an API call with an end goal being that I write all results to a CSV file, I was able to get everything working, except for the fact that it only writes the first array to the CSV file. I know there are more records (arrays) because when I echo the results I typically get 10-15 results back. Below is my code that I'm using.

```
foreach ($list as $order) { 
$listOrders = array (
    array($order->getBuyerName(), $address['AddressLine1'], $address['AddressLine2'], $address['AddressLine3'], $address['City'], $address['StateOrRegion'], $address['PostalCode'], $orderinfo->getSKU())
  ); 
}

$fp = fopen('order-file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($listOrders as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Here is a sample of the one result, though there should be around 10-15:

```
"TONYA","7X XX Avenue",,,"Spokane Valley",WA,99212,B123
```

Comment: Your'e only creating a $listOrders array with one entry: `foreach ($list as $order) { 
$listOrders[] = 
    array($order->getBuyerName(), $address['AddressLine1'], $address['AddressLine2'], $address['AddressLine3'], $address['City'], $address['StateOrRegion'], $address['PostalCode'], $orderinfo->getSKU()); 
}
`

Comment: You're overwriting $listOrders on each iteration. Define it as an array before your foreach, then use what Mark said to add a new array on each loop.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense, your help along with Jan below fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You always overwrite the `$listOrders` array with each `foreach` cycle. To add element to array, use `$listOrders[] = $var` syntax, so it should look something like this

```
$listOrders = array(); 
foreach ($list as $order) { 
    $listOrders[] = array($order->getBuyerName(), $address['AddressLine1'], $address['AddressLine2'], $address['AddressLine3'], $address['City'],   $address['StateOrRegion'], $address['PostalCode'], $orderinfo->getSKU()); 
}
```